# C:\ was unexpected at this time. while trying to setup a venv using conda

Tags: python, conda, python-venv, faster-rcnn

I am trying to setup a venv from command prompt using conda. I have made sure that i'm running the command prompt as administrator.

https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10

While trying to perform step 2e from this step by step guide I keep getting an error on the command prompt

**C:\ was unexpected at this time.**

when I perform the following command

set PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\FYP\FYP-FINAL\FASTER-RCNN\tensorflowZ\models;C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\FYP\FYP-FINAL\FASTER-RCNN\tensorflowZ\models\research;C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\FYP\FYP-FINAL\FASTER-RCNN\tensorflowZ\models\research\slim

This is what the folder hierarchy looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running these commands from **Anaconda** command prompt or **system** command prompt?
You're expected to use the first one right...

> From the Start menu in Windows, search for the **Anaconda Prompt utility**, right click on it, and click “Run as Administrator”

Comment: yes I am using anaconda prompt